# How can I get layer's data using Action Manager, excluding layers with specific layerSet?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have make this **function** so to get **data** of every **layer** with **Bevel and Emboss** effect, within a **document**. Now I am looking for a way to do the **same** thing, but excluding a specific group (**layerSet**).

```
function getLayersData()
{
    var lyrs = [];
    var layers = 1;
    while (true)
    {
        ref = new ActionReference();
        ref.putIndex(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), layers);
        try
        {
            var d1 = executeActionGet(ref);
            var d2 = executeActionGet(ref);
            var d3 = executeActionGet(ref);
            var d4 = executeActionGet(ref);
        }
            catch (err)
        {
            break;
        };
        var c2t = function (s){return app.charIDToTypeID(s);};
        var s2t = function (s){return app.stringIDToTypeID(s);};
        var lyr = {};
        lyr.type = d1.getInteger(s2t("layerKind"));
        lyr.name = d1.getString(c2t("Nm  "));
        lyr.id = d1.getInteger(s2t("layerID"));
        if (checkbox1.value == true)
        {
            ref.putEnumerated( c2t("Lyr "), c2t("Ordn"), c2t("Trgt") );
            if (d1.hasKey(s2t('layerEffects')))
            {
                d1 = d1.getObjectValue(s2t('layerEffects'));
                if (d1.hasKey(s2t('bevelEmboss')))
                {
                    d1 = d1.getObjectValue(s2t('bevelEmboss'));
                        // etc
                    d2 = d1.getObjectValue(s2t('highlightColor'));
                        // etc
                    d3 = d1.getObjectValue(s2t('shadowColor'));
                        // etc
                    d4 = d1.getObjectValue(c2t('TrnS'));
                        // etc
                    lyrs.push(lyr);
                };
            };
        }
        else
        {
            lyrs.push(lyr);
        };
        layers++;
    };    
    return lyrs;
};
```

For example, let's say we have five groups by the names Group1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

In each group we have four vectors with the same name. "Shape 1", all of them.

I want to list all these "Shape 1" vectors, except the ones within Group 5!!!

I have found the way to list all group names into another function. So I just need this function, the one I am showing, to check the parent name for every layer and if layer is a child of this group to be excluded!!!

Answer (score 1):

Working with groups within scripting is a pain and some scripts can get slow depending on the number of groups and layers you have There isn't anything systematic or logical to their ordering available from the DOM :(

However, what you can do is is loop over all the layers with recursion and exclude the ones you don't want. I've pieced together a script that will loop over all layers and record group layers names and ignore group 5. You should be able to put together something that you want to use from that.

```
// group layer vegetables
var allLayers = new Array();

// hold an array that we want to ignore the names of
var excludeLayers = ["Group 5"];


var theLayers = collect_all_layers(app.activeDocument, 0, excludeLayers);

var s = "Groups:\n";
for (var i = 0; i < allLayers.length; i++)
{
  s += allLayers[i] + "\n"
}

alert(s);


function do_stuff(alayer)
{
  // do stuff!
  alert(alayer.name);
}


// function collect all layers
function collect_all_layers (theParent, level, exclude)
{
  for (var m = theParent.layers.length - 1; m >= 0; m--)
  {


    var theLayer = theParent.layers[m];


    if (theLayer.typename == "LayerSet")
    {
      for (i = 0; i< exclude.length; i++)
      {
        if (theLayer.name == exclude[i])
        {
          alert ("Found " + exclude[i] + " and ignoring it.");
        }
        else
        {
          allLayers.push(theLayer.name);
        }
      }
    }

    // apply the function to layersets;
    if (theLayer.typename == "ArtLayer")
    {
      // find the art layers
      do_stuff(theLayer)
    }
    else
    {
      collect_all_layers(theLayer, level + 1, excludeLayers);
    }
  }
}
```